# How to avoid auto-playing Youtube videos in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, media-player

I want implement play and stop button same sd youtube when webview is loaded with Youtube URL. I used below code but when it loads in webview it starts playing (auto-play). I just want to load it in webview and not auto-play it. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
UIWebView *videoview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,80,275.0,150)];
        NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:strpreview];
        NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
        [videoview loadRequest:nsrequest];
        [self addSubview:videoview];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rather than loading request in Webview directly. Can you go for embedding using iFrame in Webview. That would be a better option I suppose. It would open native iPhone video player in iPhone.

Comment: @ParthBhatt: can you example code? thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to create an load an embedded video in iPhone using iFrame

```
NSString *yourURL = @"http://www.cloudstringers.com:14556/ingCloud/users/400010003/mp4_320p/efda2f8a618be8e4a36b81d31251752820130710115909.mp4";      
NSString *embedHTML =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                          <html><head>\
                          <style type=\"text/css\">\
                          body {\
                          background-color: #666666;\
                          padding:%f %f %f %f;\
                          color: blue;\
                          }\
                          </style>\
                          </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                          <iframe height=\"%f\" width=\"%f\" title=\"YouTube Video\" class=\"youtube-player\" src=\"%@" ></iframe>\
                          </body></html>",paddingTop,paddingRight,paddingBottom,paddingLeft,videoHeight,videoWidth,yourURL];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Hope this helps. Do let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: @NGOT This only works for youtube URL. I have a separate code implemented for Vimeo. Do you need Vimeo as well?

Comment: I need implement for http://www.cloudstringers.com:14556/ingCloud/users/400010003/mp4_320p/efda2f8a618be8e4a36b81d31251752820130710115909.mp4

Comment: Thanks much, it work now :) but if i want to view video in this frame, not full screen ????

Comment: Viewing Video in this frame is possible in iPad but not in iPhone. In iPhone by default it loads the Quicktime Video Player which is its inbuilt player.

Comment: OK, thanks much. And can I ask you a question??? I use NSParseXML to parse data that response from Server, I want to get all value accept all NULL value. Exmaple: my xml: <FILE><STATE>2</STATE><MEMO/></FILE>. In <MEMO> is null, how can i get null value???

Comment: I used code but when value null,it missed value null : if (XML_FIELD == MEMO)
    {
        NSLog(@"Value %@",string);
       [MemoArray insertObject:string atIndex:0];
    }

Comment: @NGOT: Go to your Question on NSXMLParser which you have posted. I have posted my comment there.